# Argument 1 passed to Builder::__construct() must implement interface Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface, none given

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, knpmenubundle

Using Symfony 3.3.12, i'm trying to use my menu builder as a service, this is configured in AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml and imported in main config.yml as

```
imports:
   - { resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

services.yml

```
##########################################################################
 # Menu Section   
 ##########################################################################
 AppBundle\Menu\Builder:
     arguments: 
         $factory: '@knp_menu.factory'
         $doctrine: '@doctrine'
         $token: '@security.token_storage'
     public: true
     tags:
         - { name: knp_menu.menu_builder, method: sidebarMenu, alias: sidebar }
```

But i get this error when renderd as

```
{{ knp_menu_render('sidebar', {'template': 'Menu/knp_sidebar_menu.html.twig', 'allow_safe_labels': true, 'currentClass':'active'}) }}
```

> Argument 1 passed to Builder::__construct() must implement interface
>   Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface, none given, called in
>   /home/demousr/app/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu-bundle/Provider/BuilderAliasProvider.php
>   on line 121

This is my builder

```
namespace AppBundle\Menu;

use \Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use \AppBundle\Menu\Loader\NodeLoader;
use \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

class Builder {

    private $factory;
    private $doctrine;
    private $token;

    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory, Registry $doctrine, TokenStorage $token) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->token = $token->getToken();
    }

    public function sidebarMenu(array $options) {

        $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
        $nodeLoader = new NodeLoader($this->factory, $this->token);

        $menu->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'nav nav-sidebar');

        $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        $tree = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Menu\Menu')->findOneByMenu('main');
        $roots = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Menu\MenuItem')->getRootNodesByTree($tree);

        foreach($roots as $root){

            $item = $nodeLoader->load($root);

            if(null !== $item){
                $menu->addChild($item);
            }
        }

        return $menu;
    }

}
```

I can't find where i'm wrong

Comment: I don't use this bundle but the error message seems to indicate the AliasProvider is trying to new your builder instead of pulling it from the container.  The code on github seems to confirm this though the line number is different.  Take a peek inside of the source code and see what line 121 is doing.

Comment: @Cerad on line 121 of BuilderAliasProvider `$builder = new $class();`  it's creating a new object without injecting dependencies. I think it should use [BuilderServiceProvider](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Provider/BuilderServiceProvider.php) instead . It seems that my builder is not recognized as a service

Comment: Yep.  BuilderServiceProvider pulls from the container.

Comment: @Cerad ok but why it isen't used? I've added the right tag to service definition... [documentation here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/menu_builder_service.html)

Comment: @JackSkeletron can you try to declare your service manually (all dependencies)

Comment: Maybe someone who uses the bundle can chime in.  I'm guessing it's because you are using the class name as your service id.  I'd be tempted to say try setting the alias to the class name and see what happens but that is purely a shot in the dark.  I'd suggest following the example in the docs exactly and see what happens.  I know the new container autowire stuff can be confusing at best but the old style of creating service definitions will still work.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you for trying :) I have a bunch of other services configured as this (voter etc.) that are working without any problem :\

Comment: Ok, i've just changed the class name in MenuBuilder and the method to createSidebarMenu, and changed the service id with new class name and now it works. Just a big mistery to me.

Comment: Looking at the [config options](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) I think each provider is being checked in turn.  And since any builder classes under menu are being defined as a builder then the alias provider picks it up before the service provider has a chance.  Might be interesting to try configuring the providers section under knp_menu.  Of course since you have it working, might also be best to just leave it and move on.  And consider posting your final service definition as an answer just for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just changed the class name in MenuBuilder and the method to createSidebarMenu, and changed the service id with new class name and now it works. Just a big mistery to me.

service.yml

```
##########################################################################
# Menu Section   
##########################################################################
AppBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder:
    arguments: 
        $factory: '@knp_menu.factory'
        $doctrine: '@doctrine'
        $token: '@security.token_storage'
    public: true
    tags:
        - { name: knp_menu.menu_builder, method: createSidebarMenu, alias: sidebar }
```

And this is **MenuBuilder.php**

```
class MenuBuilder {

    private $factory;
    private $doctrine;
    private $token;

    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory, Registry $doctrine, TokenStorage $token) {
       $this->factory = $factory;
       $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
       $this->token = $token->getToken();
    }

    public function createSidebarMenu(array $options) {
        # code
    }
}
```